# Как выбирать где создавать экземпляры класса, в динамической памяти или на стеке?

Tags: c++, классы, память, архитектура, стек

В ходе разработки достаточно большого проекта, я столкнулся с тем, что экземпляры классов у меня созданы все как-то хаотически: что-то в динамической памяти, что-то в стеке. Я пришел к тому, что у меня нет однозначных правил когда и как я создаю объект класса и это сеет некоторый бардак.

Единственное правильно, которое я обнаружил: в main-e я выделяю объекты в стеке(только если они не синглтон, как конфиг например)(но их там собственно не очень много, менее 5 штук - конфиг, работа основного алгоритма, запись результатов в бд. Вот уже внутри алгоритма и бд полнейший хаос). Можно добавить то, что если объект класса мне нужен только в пределах метода, то тоже не выделяю динамически(хотя наверное, если метод вызывается n раз стоило бы данный объект хранить в классе).

В  общем я пришел к выводу, что я не знаю как создавать объекты и где их хранить и в каких случаях, и в этом смысле у меня отсутствует система как в проекта, так и в голове.
Подскажите, есть ли какие-то правила по этой теме или как вообще разобраться в этом всём?

Comment: Первое правило _ стремиться хорошо организовывать что бы это ни было.  Общих правил не может быть, если хорошо организуете свою работу, вы всегда знаете кого куда и на какую роль определить. Не важно, что обязательно найдется кто то, кто бы сделал лучше... Сначала нужно спланировать схему работы, а потом начинать работать.

Comment: В нормальном коде не должно быть `new/delete`. Если можно,  на стеке. Если это невозможно технически, то `unique_ptr/shared_ptr`. Если нужны группы - `vector`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy unique_ptr/shared_ptr вобще-то указывают на память из кучи выделенную через new - их цель не сократить количество там выделений памяти, а предоставить программисту удобный способ работы с памятью минимизируя ошибки связанные с памятью/ресурсом.

Comment: @ampawd, где я упомянул сокращение количества выделений памяти?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy у меня сложилось такое впечатление - но сейчас вроде вижу что не об этом была речь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всегда на стеке, если нет какой-то конкретной причины использовать кучу.

Возможные причины:

- Это массив переменного размера - в стандартном С++ их нельзя создать на стеке.
- Объект должен пережить выход из функции, где был создан. Причем пережить в своем оригинальном виде, а не как `return`утая копия.
- Объект слишком большой. (Несколько килобайт? При размере стека в единицы мегабайт.)
- ...?

И как правильно пишет @StanislavVolodarskiy, в вашем коде не должно быть `new` и `delete`. Это низкоуровневые инструменты для авторов контейнеров и умных указателей: `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr` и подобных. Используйте их вместо `new` и `delete`.

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что работа с объектами на стеке будет быстрее, в силу того, что динамическую память выделить можно только через ОС, а это не прогнозируемое по времени событие?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher В целом да. Я не уверен, что для этого каждый раз дергается ОС (системным вызовом), по идее стандартная библиотека должна запрашивать память крупными кусками, и нарезать оттуда куски по запросу.

Comment: HolyBlackCat
да , вектор например начинает с 32 байт и по заполнению запрашивает каждый раз в 2 раза больше. Мы в универе свой вектор на си так писали

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Я имел в виду сами malloc/new, а не контейнеры, написанные поверх них.

Comment: HolyBlackCat

в этом плане malloc честный и он запросит ровно столько памяти, сколько попросишь в аргументе

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Вы не поняли, что я вам написал. Malloc может попросить у ОС больше памяти, чем вы у него попросили. А когда его вызовут второй раз, не обращаться к ОС, а выдать кусок из своих запасов.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на ваш вопрос тянет на целую статью из нескольких листов,  не считая массу ожидаемых обсуждений. Если объекты могут быть кандидатом  на удаление в данной области видимости, то создайте динамически, или если для их количества в стеке может место не хватать. Например многие пользуются только стандартным вектором `std::vector`, или советуют его при любых обстоятельствах. Но вы должны смотреть для чего храните эти объекты, как будете ими пользоваться, какие действия будут выполняться с контейнером и так далее(точно так же, как и организовывают любое дело).

Иногда(для примера) может быть уместно создать свою собственную тривиальную хэш_таблицу, чем пользоваться стандартным. Существующий любой способ хранения имеет свои преимущества и недостатки, но если не нужно будет выращивать контейнер или удалять некоторые объекты по ходу, то  логично их хранить статически в таких, как `std::valarray` `std::array`..., в собственноручно написанном или стандартном, но точно не в векторе или других контейнерах, которые используют динамическую память, просто потому что это дороже и не специфично для данного метода. Нет общих правил дизайна и архитектуры _ каждому свое...